# Get datetime from MongoDB Atlas - Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Is there a way to get the MongoDB server datetime using nodejs? Please understand that what I need is not to add the timestamp to a field in a document but to retrieve the date and time from the **MongoDB Atlas** server to be sent in the nodejs response.

---

I've tried,

```
client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
client.connect().then(function () {
    var ob = client.db("dbname").runCommand({
        serverStatus: 1,
        repl: 1
    });
    res.send(ob);
});
```

but this gives me,

```
TypeError: client.db(...).runCommand is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the command in the admin database and prior to the operation you need to grant a role to the executing user with the [`serverStatus`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Admin.html#serverStatus) action

```
client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect().then(function() {
    const adminDb = client.db("dbName").admin();

    adminDb.serverStatus(function(err, status) {
        res.send(status.localTime);
        client.close();
    });
});
```